# Forward slash gets removed when using YAML deployment file for Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, yaml, containers, azure-cli

Im trying to deploy 2 containers in a group within Azure by using the azure-cli in Powershell.
Becuase i want the containers with a private ip address i use the following template:

```
apiVersion: 2022-04-01-preview
name: uptime-kuma
properties:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-with-ssl
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:1.15.5-alpine
      ports:
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx
  - name: uptime-kuma-app
    properties:
      image: louislam/uptime-kuma:latest
      ports:
      - port: 3001
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: uptime-kuma
        mountPath: /app/data
  volumes:
  - secret:
      ssl.crt: <removed for this post>
      ssl.key: <removed for this post>
      nginx.conf: <removed for this post>
    name: nginx-config
  - name: uptime-kuma
    emptyDir: {}
  ipAddress:
    type: Private
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 443
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  subnetIds:
   - id:  '/subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourceGroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/S2S_LAN/subnets'
     name: 'IPSEC_LAN'
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

It does wrong on the subnetIds.id part, i get the following error:

```
(InvalidVirtualNetworkLocation) Container group 'uptime-kuma' is in location 'westeurope' while virtual network 'subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourceGroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks' is in location '<null>'. The container group and virtual network should be in same location.
Code: InvalidVirtualNetworkLocation
Message: Container group 'uptime-kuma' is in location 'westeurope' while virtual network 'subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourceGroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks' is in location '<null>'. The container group and virtual network should be in same location.
```

As you can see, it says for the virual network that the location is  because the virtual network can not be found because there is a / missing before "subscriptions/".
When i add another one, so it will be:

```
subnetIds:
   - id:  '//subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourceGroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/S2S_LAN/subnets'
```

Then the location is correct and it can be found, but then i get the error that the permission are wrong because it sees it as this :

```
The client '<removed for this post>' with object id '<removed for this post>' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/write' on scope '/subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourcegroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/uptime-kuma'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action' on the linked scope(s) '//subscriptions/<removed for this post>/resourceGroups/Homelab/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/S2S_LAN/subnets' or the linked scope(s) are invalid.
```

I don't know how to fix this.. has anyone encountered this before? I'm in search for help.

EDIT: After rebuilding it to a Bicep template i get the same issues. So it has to be the API version of the component, so i tried different versions, all the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my environment getting the exact error as you are facing .

[image]

You need to assigned a [***Network contributor***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json#network-contributor) build in role `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action` to your managed identity.You can use these operations in your own [Azure custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to provide granular access control to resources in Azure. I can not test in my environment as I don't have privileged to assigned roles to the resources you require admin privilege to assigned this roles to your resources.

Similar kind of issue has also raise on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/745497/getting-error-about-linkedauthorizationfailed-when.html) and MSFT has suggested the same.